# Date range filter in mongodb Groupby aggregation query

Tags: mongodb, group-by, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I want to filter each group aggregation by different date-range.For **dayMonthStatus** I want to filter by **$currentDate - 1** , for **monthStatus** - **current monthnumber**, for **weekStatus 
 - current weeknumber**.

Sample json:

```
{ 
    "createdAt" : "2019-10-02T04:55:13.472Z", 
    "Day-month" : "2-10", 
    "Month" : NumberInt(10), 
    "Year" : NumberInt(2019), 
    "Week" : NumberInt(39)
}
```

I have tried $cond operator but get only blank values or error **"errmsg" : "An object representing an expression must have exactly one field"**, below is the groupby aggregation code on which I want to apply filter.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    // current aggregation stages,
    {
        $facet: {
            "dayMonthStatus": [
                { $group: { _id: { status: "$Ctrans.status", "dayMonth": "$Day-month" }, count: { $sum: 1 } } }
            ],
            "monthStatus": [
                { $group: { _id: { status: "$Ctrans.status", "month": "$Month" }, count: { $sum: 1 } } }
            ],
            "yearStatus": [
                { $group: { _id: { status: "$Ctrans.status", "year": "$Year" }, count: { $sum: 1 } } }
            ],
            "weekStatus": [
                { $group: { _id: { status: "$Ctrans.status", "week": "$Week" }, count: { $sum: 1 } } }
            ]
        }
    }
])
```

I have tried $match in groupby in below format:

```
"dayMonthStatus": [
                { $group: { _id: { status: "$Customer-transaction.status", "dayMonth": "$Day-month" }, count: { $sum: 1 },
                     } },{ $match: {"dayMonth": { '$gte': "1-10", '$lt': "3-10"}}}
            ]
```

Comment: Use `$match` stage within each facet.

Comment: I am getting **"A pipeline stage specification object must contain exactly one field."** on using  $match

Comment: Please show how you have used. See these [examples](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/index.html#example).

Comment: I have updated the question with sample json and how i have tried $match

Comment: For example, for the facet "yearStatus", you want to match for a particular year or a range?

Comment: I want to match with year "2019" for facet "yearStatus" , similarly for monthStatus i want to match with "Month"

Comment: Use the $match _before_ the $group.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202559/discussion-between-rahul-anand-and-prasad).